# EventBus use, memory and architecture

Tags: android, event-bus

I'm starting using EventBus in my app and it's really nice to use, it solve a lot of problems and simplify the code, and the propagation all over the app with all threads and everything is fantastic, but I'm feeling I maybe abusing of the use of events.

For now everything is fine, I'm testing in powerful devices and the app response is really nice, but I have a lot of coding to do yet and I'm starting to question myself how will affect having too much events triggering all over the app.

So the question is for anyone that have experience with that library if there is some problems with having a lot of events in my app, if there is some known memory issues related to the use of this events. I'm trying to use it wisely, but it's difficult not to include it a lot in your architecture because it's a really nice functionality. Anyway if you have something to say about the subject will be nice because I have a lot of coding to do and will be a problem have my architecture wrong and have to go back to make changes because some issues related to the events.

PD. I'm talking about native Android app, with a lot of networking

Thx

Comment: My opinion only, I personally find that I abuse events much easier than I do the `listener-observer` pattern, (or, on iOS, the delegate pattern), even though they are very similar. There's nothing inherently wrong architecturally with events, but you've got to be careful with them. If you feel this way at the beginning, then there's a reason for it. I'd try to stick to `listener-observer` unless the only way to achieve something is by using events. Just to reiterate, this is my opinion only.

Comment: Yes, my concern is that it can became tricky and hard to maintain and scale, for now I'm using volley library for my networking and I'm handling all my callbacks with events and I'm using events also to critical errors/issues in my app that need to stop the execution and need to be propagated all over the app, like for example ask for internet connection before a web service call and if not show a dialog screen in the current visible activity/fragment or a Toast, but I'm finding myself inclined to use it more and more and that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a problem having many events in your app as long as you follow components lifecycle changes: register for events in `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop()`. If you do this, then only a relatively small subset of active components will be subscribed for events, which makes whole solution lean.

In my app I had some issue with the central singleton event bus instance, that's why I use a [lightweight and fast event bus](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus) capable to attach to an activity and respect it's lifecycle. With it I can have a bus instance per activity, which is very lightweight.

Comment: Yes I'm dealing with the register/unregister events really well in my project, the EventBus library I'm using handle that part pretty well, was looking your library and the examples, it looks nice. In the EventBus library from greenrobot the event handler singleton is provided by the library already so you just need to register and that's it. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you are saying and I am also working on a pretty massive codebase in our company and we use event bus a lot. You just have to be careful with it but it can get annoying to find out which places in the app are subscribed to a certain event. If there are multiple subscriptions, then having to fish through the app is not very fun. As a solution to this, I love to use this amazing Android Studio plugin for Otto Event Bus which will seamlessly take you from and event to its subscribers or vice versa.

`https://github.com/square/otto-intellij-plugin`

This will really help make navigation between events and subscribers a LOT easier.

Comment: Yes it look like a nice tool but I'm not using Otto but the greenrobot EventBus library: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus. I'm dealing with the amount of calls and the callbacks trying to be as much organized as I can in a big project, for now it's looks good, let's see how maintenance and scalability looks like in time. Thx for the response, don't accept it as correct coz it's used for Otto only but is a nice tool for others so you got my up vote.